# Modify a csv column data type from character to numeric to apply range function

Tags: r, rstudio, sapply, read.csv

The contents of csv file is given below:
[image: Data set with details of an automobile]

Here the column horsepower is character by default. When I applied range function in horsepower as :

```
    sapply(Auto[,4],range)
```

The following error message appers:

```
    Error in Summary.factor(17L, na.rm = FALSE) :
```

‘range’ not meaningful for factors

So I tried to covert the character to numeric as:

```
   as.numeric(as.character(Auto$horsepower))
```

This results in the warning message:

```
   NAs introduced by coercion
```

After the above step also I am not able to apply the range function.
How to use range function in horsepower column ? Please note that data set contains a character '?' in horsepower column line number 127.

Comment: As an fyi -  it’s best to avoid using images of code/data and [here’s why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Note that you can quickly get your data out of your R session and onto SO by calling `dput(my_df)` and copy/pasting the result.  If your data are large, do `dput(head(my_df))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue here is that `horsepower` was converted to a factor when the CSV file was read into R. This is due to the presence of the `?` character.

You can avoid this using *e.g.*

```
Auto <- read.csv("myfile.csv", 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                 na.strings = "?")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
range(as.numeric(as.character(Auto$horsepower)), na.rm=TRUE)
```

If you want to convert a numeric-looking factor to an actual numeric, it is correct to use `as.numeric(as.character())`.  For you, this introduces NAs because you have values like "?" in the column for `horsepower` and R doesn't know how to turn a "?" into a numeric, so it turns it into an NA.

Now, you can calculate the `range`, but you need to tell `range` to "skip" the NAs with the argument `na.rm=TRUE`.

Comment: is to do like this : sapply(Auto[,4],range(as.numeric(as.character(Auto$horsepower)), na.rm=TRUE))

Comment: Because you are only calculating the range for one column of data, you don't need `sapply`.

Comment: This solution worked. Just curious to know what happens in the case of sapply, like this : sapply(Auto[,1:5],range).   The 4th column horsepower is character, so how to handle this situation.

Comment: Before trying to take the range of any variable, make sure it's numeric.  Then you can call `sapply(Auto[ , 1:5], range, na.rm=T)`.